# Is it necessary to send a share of the newly created token to contract address?

Tags: solidity, binance-smart-chain

am new to token creation.
I have successfully created my token on bscmainet and claimed all the coins, now I have them in my Metamask wallet.

A lot of tutorials recommend sending part of the supply to the contract address of the token itself. Is this a necessary step?

From what I understood, I will need to provide liquidity on DEX out of my own wallet not from the contract address so what's the point in sending a share to contract address?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending tokens to the token contract is useful if there's a direct way to buy the tokens through your contract. Example:

```
function buy() external payable {
    uint256 amount = calculateAmount(msg.value);

    // send tokens from this contract address to the user
    transfer(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

But if there's no way to retrieve the tokens sent to the contract address (e.g. you're planning to sell them only through exchanges), there's no point of sending them to the contract address.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Petr. 
I am trying now to burn the tokens that I had sent to the contact address, is there a way to achieve that? 
I tried to use "burn from" on the "write contract" tab under "contract" on bscscan.com but It retrurned "transaction expected to fail", proceed anyway?".
The "burn" function actually worked but it burns tokens in my wallet not the tokens in the contract address...

Comment: @Naim It depends on your `burnFrom()` implementation. But generally, you cannot transfer tokens from an address that you don't own private key to (e.g. the contract address), unless the contract code is explicitly allowing you to do so. For example by implementing the burnFrom function like this: `balances[_from] -= value; totalSupply -= value;`